# Swiftui SortDescriptor - Personalise sorting

Tags: swiftui

```
    @State var sortDescriptor: SortDescriptor<Spell> = SortDescriptor(\.name)
```

I want to define the SortDescriptor so that letters come first than numbers.

Example: ["2st", "Cant", "1st"] -> ["Cant", "1st", "2nd"]

I don't know how to.

Comment: do you need to use SortDescriptor? Or just need sorting?

Comment: I wanted to see if it was possible with sortDeacriptor but i accept other alternatives

Answer (score 0):

```
let array = ["2nd", "Cant", "1st", "Abc", "12some", "hello"]

extension Array where Element == String {
    func sortedNrLast() -> Self {
        self.filter { !"0123456789".map {$0}.contains($0.first) }.sorted() +
        self.filter { "0123456789".map {$0}.contains($0.first) }.sorted()
    }
}

print(array.sortedNrLast())
```